# selenium - wait until dropbox2 is refreshed based on value in dropbox1

Tags: selenium

in my application, value of dropbox2 depends on dropbox1. So if user select value from dropbox1, based on value in dropbox1, values in dropbox2 get populated.

During the selenium testing, I get below error when i try to select value from dropbox2

```
Cannot locate element with text: Others
```

How can i wait until values in dropbox2 get populated based on value in dropbox1.

I tried to use Thread.sleep though I know that is not a good way and shouldnt be used.

I am new to selenium but experienced java developer.

Comment: I would split it into 2 tests, first test the dropbox2 has been created , then a separate test for the values

Comment: Your code trials and relevant `HTML` please.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help:

```
public static void waitForAjaxToFinish() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wdriver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0").equals(true);
        }

    });
}
```